# Azure DevOps Api - Get Remaining Work Days

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

My Problem: I want to get the remaining workdays inside a sprint via the Azure DevOps Api.
I couldn't find any endpoints containing this information. 
Is there a way to get this information without calculating it manually?

[image]

Comment: Which language? I think i've done something similar in powershell